# Configure IntelliJ IDEA to always ignore Git Roots created by Maven Release Plugin at target/checkout

Tags: git, maven, intellij-idea

IntelliJ 11.1.3 keeps on pestering me with a lovely notification along the lines of:

```
Unregistered Git root detected
The Directory /....../target/checkout is under Git, but is not registered in the Settings.
Configure Ignore VCS root errors
```

Now I can click the Ignore VCS root errors to dismiss the error... but then I will have ignored potentially other issues... so that would be bad.

I don't want to add the git root, because it's a semi-temporary root.

I don't want to clean the Maven project because I need to hold onto the root for some secondary post-release tasks.

What I want is a *global* setting that I can apply to IntelliJ that says: “If you see a Git ROOT on a path that ends with `/target/checkout` just ignore it”

What I do not want is to have to repeat doing something every time I re-import the pom.xml or for every project I open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible to solve this problem the way you like right now, there is already a [bug report for it](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-83721) in YouTrack, feel free to star/vote and track the progress.